# Is CSS "vertical-align:central" correct?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012 update 4 prompts the “central” as a value of vertical-align. Please refer to the screenshot below.

[image: Visual Studio 2012 showing vertical-align: central]

But I cannot find the “central” value in [the CSS reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align). Does this value exist?

Comment: It should be `vertical-align : middle`. `central` might not work cross browser's. I don't think it's a valid value

Comment: Do you mean that IE supports this value? what is difference with :middle? Thanks.

Comment: No, It's not a valid value. I have seen many values that are not w3c valid in VS 2013. Not sure, if there is some documentation on MS sites. You might want to check the MS forums if you want to know

Comment: Nope, according to MSDN, "vertical-align:central" does not exist. (Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531179(v=vs.85).aspx )

Comment: @CaseyFalk That was quick.

Comment: Actually, it appears that `central` *was*, at one point, valid as per the W3C's working draft for line (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-linebox/#vertical-align-prop), although seemingly no longer supported in most browsers. However, the SVG 1.1 recommendation for Text describes another vertical-alignment-defining property called `dominant-baseline` which *does* accept `central` as a value, albeit only for elements of an SVG document (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#BaselineAlignmentProperties).

Comment: FWIW, http://bl.ocks.org/eweitnauer/7325338 currently has a working demonstration of how the different `dominant-baseline` values are interpreted by your web browser.

Comment: Good find, @Aaron! I'll edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

No, if it is not anywhere in the documentation then it should not be used. Stick with something that is documented and supported across browsers.

Documentation: [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align), [W3 Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align), and [W3's current Visual Formatting Details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)

(edit: thanks to [Jukka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084437/jukka-k-korpela) for catching the obsolete link)

Excerpt from Mozilla's rule-book:

```
Formal syntax: baseline | sub | super | text-top | text-bottom | middle | top | bottom | <percentage> | <length>
vertical-align: baseline     /* keyword values */
vertical-align: sub
vertical-align: super
vertical-align: text-top
vertical-align: text-bottom
vertical-align: middle
vertical-align: top
vertical-align: bottom
vertical-align: 10em          /* <length> values */
vertical-align: 4px
vertical-align: 20%           /* <percentage> values */

vertical-align: inherit
```

**However**, as noted by [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030243/aaron), "central *was*, at one point, valid as per the [W3C's working draft for line](http://w3.org/TR/css3-linebox/#vertical-align-prop) (from 2002), although seemingly **no longer supported in most browsers**. The SVG 1.1 recommendation for Text describes another vertical-alignment-defining property called [dominant-baseline](http://w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#BaselineAlignmentProperties) which does accept central as a value, albeit only for elements of an SVG document. (emphasis mine and paraphrased)"

Comment: CSS1 is seriously outdated and should not be cited as reference.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I didn't even realize. I need more coffee today apparently. Fixing the link now. Thanks for catching that, @Jukka.

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align:central` still exists in the CSS Level 3 drafts in the [CSS Inline Layout Module Level 3 Editor’s Draft, 13 June 2014](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-inline/#propdef-vertical-align).

The possible values list is `auto | baseline | sub | super | top | text-top | central | middle | bottom | text-bottom | percentage-units | length-units`

Of course, that doesn't mean there's any support for it in browsers right now,

Answer (score 0):

From the W3 website:

> vertical-align:
>   baseline|length|sub|super|top|text-top|middle|bottom|text-bottom|initial|inherit;

Like Ani said, it should be `vertical-align: middle`.
It does not exist, Although it might be implemented in some other browser.